# Extracting semester of a given date

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I need to extract the semester of a given date and I ended up with this code:

```
df['semester']= df.my_date.dt.year.astype(str) + '-S'+ np.where(df.my_date.dt.quarter.gt(2),2,1).astype(str)
```

Can someone explain to me how this part works:

```
np.where(df.my_date.dt.quarter.gt(2),2,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) if condition is `True`, here [`Series.dt.quarter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html) is greater by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) like `2` set `2` else `1`.

So it is same like:

```
np.where(df.my_date.dt.quarter > 2,2,1)
```